# Genetic Algorithm for feature selection in R

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm, r-caret, feature-selection

I am new to R and I searched the Internet heavily, but I could not get it working. I am trying to do feature selection using genetic algorithms with fitness function being area under curve (AUC) of ROC of random forest model.

I tried looking at the genalg, GA and caret packages, but I could not get it working. For the fitness function, I am trying the random forest model and using the auc (area under curve) of ROC as a measure.

The fitness function:

```
library("randomForest")
library("ROCR")

set.seed(71)
#load data
CM1 <- read.arff("CM1.arff")
CM1_train <- CM1[1:240, ]
CM1_val <- CM1[241:nrow(CM1) ,] #validation set


#random forest - train model
model.rf <- randomForest(Defective~., data = CM1_train, importance = T, proximity = T, keep.forest = T, test = CM1_val)

#to find AUC of ROC
model.rf.probability = predict(model.rf, type = "prob", newdata = CM1_val)[ ,2]
model.rf.pred = prediction(model.rf.probability, CM1_val$Defective)
model.rf.perf = performance(model.rf.pred, "tpr", "fpr")

plot(model.rf.perf, main = "ROC Curve for Random Forest", col = 2, lwd = 2)
abline(a = 0, b = 1, lwd = 2, lty = 2, col = "gray")

auc <- performance(model.rf.pred, "auc")
auc <- unlist(slot(auc, "y.values"))
```

How do I write the program for feature selection using genetic algorithm. (I know that we have to represent the feature as binary strings, but I could not come up with the code).

Comment: Can you try the code [here](http://atm.amegroups.com/article/view/18292/html)